# Converting decimal number into 2's complement using 16 bits

Tags: decimal, twos-complement

The problem:

What is the decimal number -234 in 2's complement using 16 bits?

---

Do I just have to convert 234 to binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, converting it to binary is sufficient. The answer is `0xff16`.

Also, you can try using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-234+to+binary) to verify your calculations.